# Is it possible to create a trigger to copy values into same field in another row (in the same table)?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following table `test` with the fields

```
id (PK), 
Project Code (CFK), 
item code (CFK) 
date_code
```

rows could look like:

```
id, project code, item code, date code
1,  project1,     item1,     1220 
2,  project1,     item2,     1224
3,  project1,     item1,     null
3,  project1,     item4,     null
4,  project1,     item1,     null
```

To update date code I can do that with a simple update table

```
update table test
set date_code='1220' 
where project_code='project1' and item_code='item1'
```

But can this be done with a trigger on insert and update?

I want the trigger find the same/matching composite foreign key fields (project code & item code) like in update table syntax and copy the same value in other rows for the date code field?

All the rows would exist before the date_code field is given values so it is something that is done last.

Comment: Your question suggests that your table is denormalised, and you would do well to store `date_code` in a separate table of `items` where `(project_code, item_code)` is unique/PK.

Comment: it honestly isn't. I just used date code as an example. It's not actuallly date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_projects_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON projects
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.date_code = IF(NULLIF(TRIM(NEW.date_code), '') IS NULL,
  (
    SELECT date_code 
      FROM projects
     WHERE project_code = NEW.project_code 
       AND item_code = NEW.item_code
     LIMIT 1
  ), NEW.date_code);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_projects_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON projects
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.date_code = IF(NULLIF(TRIM(NEW.date_code), '') IS NULL,
  (
    SELECT date_code 
      FROM projects
     WHERE project_code = NEW.project_code 
       AND item_code = NEW.item_code
     LIMIT 1
  ), NEW.date_code);
```

Now we can insert and update row into projects table

```
-- insert a new row and let the trigger to set date_code automatically
INSERT INTO projects VALUES (5, 'project1', 'item1', NULL);

-- update all rows that currently have NULL in date_code 
-- and let the trigger to set date_code automatically
UPDATE projects SET date_code = NULL WHERE date_code IS NULL;

-- insert a new row and explicitly set a value to date_code
INSERT INTO projects VALUES (6, 'project2', 'item1', '1115');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ccfb1/1)** demo

Comment: thats amazing and quite beyond my abilities atm to have worked that out.